# How to derivate norms?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I would like to solve this formula:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial v} \frac{1}{2} \left( \| A*v + c \|_2^2 + \|v\|_F^2 \right)
$$

Where: $ A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $, and $ v \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Without the norms it is easy, but I have no idea, how to handle the Frobenius, and 2 norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it to a form that you are more familiar without norm is an option.
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial}{\partial v} \frac{1}{2} \left( \| Av + c \|_2^2 + \|v\|_F^2 \right) \\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial v} \frac{1}{2} \left( ( Av + c)^T(Av+c) + \|v\|_2^2 \right) \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial v} \frac{1}{2} \left( (v^TA^TAv+c^TAv+v^TA^Tc + v^Tv \right) \\
&=  \frac{1}{2} \left( (2A^TAv+A^Tc+A^Tc + 2v \right) \\
&=  A^TAv+A^Tc+ v \\
&=  A^T(Av+c)+ v \\
\end{align}

Comment: Why was the $\|v\|_F^2$ changed to $\|v\|_2^2$ ?

Comment: is frobenenius norm equal to 2-norm when $v$ is a vector?